# como trabaja el cifrado SHA-256 en esta función?

Tags: javascript, hash, sha256

tengo un problema acerca de este código, estoy intentando comprender pero aun no doy con ello, tengo una duda acerca de como trabaja generando un hash el algoritmo SHA-256

```
// Convertir String a ArrayBuffer, este paso es solo necesario si quiero codificar un String
var input = new TextEncoder('utf-8').encode('palabra');

// calcular el calculo de SHA-256
crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', input)
// Wait for completion
.then(function(digest) {
    //Mostrar como cadena hexadecimal
    var view = new DataView(digest);
    var hexstr = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < view.byteLength; i++) {

        var b = view.getUint8(i);

        //Esta cadena no entiendo....recorre bytes??
        hexstr += '0123456789abcdef'[(b & 0xf0) >> 4];
        hexstr += '0123456789abcdef'[(b & 0x0f)];
}
    console.log(hexstr);
    // Otherwise, you can simply create an Uint8Array from the buffer:
    var digestAsArray = new Uint8Array(digest);
    console.log(digestAsArray);
})
 // Catch errors
  .catch(function(err) {
   console.error(err)   
});
```

Especificamente esta línea -

> ```
>     hexstr += '0123456789abcdef'[(b & 0xf0) >> 4];
>     hexstr += '0123456789abcdef'[(b & 0x0f)];
> ```

Gracias,

> Salida hash generado >

2381f1805955736a41f5966c10ab49a5b3adc40d95991d4680d7f22b54b8dae0

Answer (score 2):

No se nada de javascript pero parece que lo que hace es lo siguiente:
`b & 0xf0` está haciendo and a nivel de bits y el resultado es quedarse con el la parte alta del byte y poniendo a ceros la parte baja, osea, si b tenía el valor 0x4A, se quedaría como 0x40. Luego `>> 4` desplaza cuatro bits hacia la derecha todo, con lo que tu 0x40 pasaría a ser un 0x04. Ahora eso lo usa como índice de la cadena '0123456789abcdef' con lo que retornará el carácter de esa cadena en la posición 0x04, osea un 4.
La segunda línea es igual, pero quedándose con la parte baja de b, osea tu b inicial 0x4A se quedaría como 0x0A y usa ese valor como índice de la misma cadena, con lo que retornará el caracter A.
En definitiva lo que está es convirtiendo los números en su representación hexadecimal en una cadena de caracteres. En el ejemplo si b es 0x4A, el resultado sería una cadena de dos caracteres, el primero el carácter 4 y el segundo el carácter A.